# Return array in Python from shared library built in Go

Tags: python, go

I have the following Go file:

```
package main

import "C"

//export stringList
func stringList(a, b string) []string {
        var parserString[] string
        parserString = append(parserString, a)
        parserString = append(parserString, b)
        return parserString
}

func main() {}
```

which I then build using `go build -o stringlist.so -buildmode=c-shared stringlist.go`

Then, I try to call it in Python using

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./stringlist.so")
lib.stringList.argtypes = [c_wchar_p, c_wchar_p]
lib.stringList("hello", "world")
```

but receive the error

```
panic: runtime error: cgo result has Go pointer

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
main._cgoexpwrap_0de9d34d4a40_stringList.func1(0xc00005ce90)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:46 +0x5c
main._cgoexpwrap_0de9d34d4a40_stringList(0x7f9fdfa8eec0, 0x7f9fddaffab0, 0x7f9fdd8f46cf, 0x7ffc501ce460, 0xc00000e040, 0x2, 0x2)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:48 +0x11b
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is the problem? How can I fix it? Is `stringList` not returning a proper type?

Comment: `[]string` isn't an array, it's a slice. You have to return a C array.

Comment: How can I change it to a C array?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to convert to `C` types before returning any value, this means that your function should return `**C.char`. The Go documentation has functions that convert from `*C.chart` to `C.GoString`.

- [Cgo Wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#turning-c-arrays-into-go-slices)
- [CGO Documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

Here's a simple albeit probably leaky function; in Cgo you are responsible of 
memory management, this particular function allocates the result memory *but* if you know before calling the `Cgo` function how much memory or space you need it's possible to preallocate it.

All that it does is convert to upper case the provided strings.

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unsafe"
)

//export stringList
func stringList(a, b *C.char) **C.char {
    // convert to Go strings
    goStringA := C.GoString(a)
    goStringB := C.GoString(b)

    //... do something with the strings ...
    fmt.Println("CGO: ", goStringA)
    fmt.Println("CGO: ", goStringB)

    goStringA = strings.ToUpper(goStringA)
    goStringB = strings.ToUpper(goStringB)

    // Convert back to C strings
    // This strings _WILL NOT_ be garbage collect
    // it may be that we want to free them.
    // https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#go-strings-and-c-strings
    ra := C.CString(goStringA)
    rb := C.CString(goStringB)

    // Allocate memory for our result pointer
    resultMem := C.malloc(C.size_t(2) * C.size_t(unsafe.Sizeof(uintptr(0))))

    // Assign to the results var
    // https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#turning-c-arrays-into-go-slices
    result := (*[1<<30 - 1]*C.char)(resultMem)
    (*result)[0] = ra
    (*result)[1] = rb

    return (**C.char)(resultMem)
}

func main() {}
```

Because I'm in a `macOS` computer I have to build it like so:

```
go build -o stringlist.dylib -buildmode=c-shared main.go
```

Then I can run it with the following Python code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./stringlist.dylib')

lib.stringList.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p]
lib.stringList.restype = POINTER(c_char_p)

result = lib.stringList("hello".encode(), "world".encode())
for word in result:
    if word:
        print(word.decode('utf-8'))
```

> *NOTE*: The python code produces a segfault; I'm guessing that it's because I'm not using correctly the `ctypes` module as I'm not that familiar with. However the following C code does not segfault.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stringlist.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int n, char **args) {
    char lib_path[1000]; 
    sprintf(lib_path, "%s/stringlist.dylib", args[1]);
    void *handle = dlopen(lib_path, RTLD_LAZY);

    char** (*stringList)(char*, char*) = dlsym(handle, "stringList");
    const char *a = "hello";
    const char *b = "world";
    char **result = stringList(a, b);
    for (size_t i = 0; i< 2; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", result[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Build it like this:

```
clang main.c -o crun && ./crun
```